# Como evitar que o JSONArray se organize de ordem alfabetica?

Tags: android, json

Estou pegando os dados de um JSONArray e passando para outra String, no entanto nesse processo meus dados estão ficando em ordem alfabetica, e eu gostaria que ficasse na ordem de leitura do arquivo JSon. Isso é possível?

Comment: Você está usando `JSONArray.write`?

Comment: São os elementos do array que estão mudando de ordem (improvável) ou as propriedades dos objetos contidos no array? Se for o segundo caso, é normal, já que objetos JSON não impõem uma ordem aos seus campos. Se dá pra contornar isso, não sei te dizer.

Comment: **daniel12345smith**, você tem permissão de alterar estrutura deste JSON? Se tiver, posso ajudar.

Comment: eu tenho permissão sim.